# Parse json response from curl in github action

Tags: json, github, curl, github-actions

I have the curl request as shown below and also attached the response of curl request from the response how can I fetch the value which is under "status.azure.resource_name" and store it in some variable as I'm new to GitHub action facing some challenges if this is some programming api I could have resolved it

Request:

```
curl --location --request PUT $URL \
                  --header "$AUTH_HEADER" \
                  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
                  --data-raw "$PAYLOAD"
```

Response:

```
{
  "labels": {},
  "spec": {
    "mysql": {
      "version": "8.0",
      "sku": {
        "name": "GP_Gen5_4"
      },
      "storage_profile": {
        "storage_mb": 5120
      }
    },
    "key_vault": {
      "access_policies": [
        {
          "name": "test",
          "type": "group",
          "project": null
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "type": "azure-mysql",
  "name": "mysql",
  "id": "1234",
  "created_at": "2012-03-04T10:00:05+00:00",
  "updated_at": "2012-03-04T10:00:05+00:00",
  "project": {
    "id": "ae3dfa99",
    "name": "Test",
    "url": "www.google.com",
    "geography": "in"
  },
  "links": {
    "key_vault": {
      "endpoint": {
        "url": "",
        "description": "test.",
        "display_name": "test"
      },
      "azure_portal": {
        "url": "test",
        "description": "Link to the resource in the Azure portal.",
        "display_name": "Key Vault Azure Portal"
      }
    },
    "azure_portal": {
      "url": "test",
      "description": "Link to the resource in the Azure portal.",
      "display_name": "Azure Portal"
    },
    "endpoint": {
      "url": "test",
      "description": "Azure resource endpoint.",
      "display_name": "test"
    }
  },
  "url": "test",
  "tags": {
    "cost_center_id": "471000",
    "customer": "internal",
    "product_group": "internal",
    "environment_type": "test",
    "budget_category": "",
    "team": ""
  },
  "spiffe_id": "test",
  "status": {
    "ready": false,
    "state": "reconciling",
    "deployment": {
      "steps": {}
    },
    "azure": {
      "resource_name": "test",
      "id": null,
      "subscription_id": "test",
      "resource_group": "test"
    },
    "key_vault": {
      "access_policies": []
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve that.

1. You can use directly `jq` and read variable in bash step.
2. You can use one of existing open source actions from marketplace:

```
- name: get nested property
    id: format_script
    uses: notiz-dev/github-action-json-property@release
    with: 
        path: 'yourjson.json'
        prop_path: 'status.azure.resource_name'
- run: echo ${{steps.format_script.outputs.prop}}
```

3. Download just one property from whole JSON if you don't need a file itself:

```
- uses: senmu/download-json-property-action@v1.0.0
  with:
    url: 'https://httpbin.org/json'
    property_path: status.azure.resource_name
```

Comment: 3rd option looks good but how can i use above curl command here